# PostgreSQL. Materialized views may not be defined using bound parameters

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to create materialized views inside stored function, which has date 
range as inbound parameters.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.create_view_for_reporting(
prev_date timestamp without time zone,
curr_date timestamp without time zone)
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW public.messages_prev_day;    
    CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW public.messages_prev_day AS 
    SELECT * FROM messages
    WHERE messages.date >= prev_date AND messages.date < curr_date
    WITH NO DATA;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

Function created with no issues, though when I run it:

```
select * from public.create_view_for_reporting ('2017-05-08','2017-05-09')
```

it is failing with error

> ERROR:  materialized views may not be defined using bound parameters

So, I'm wondering if there's any possible variant to create materialized view with parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try?:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.create_view_for_reporting(
prev_date timestamp without time zone,
curr_date timestamp without time zone)
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW public.messages_prev_day;    
    execute format('CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW public.messages_prev_day AS 
    SELECT * FROM messages
    WHERE messages.date >= %L AND messages.date < %L
    WITH NO DATA',prev_date,curr_date);
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

Comment: Magnificent! Worked fine. Thank you